# RenderLink is hidden in experience editor mode

Tags: html, razor, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8.1

We are on sitecore 8.1 update 3 and Glass Mapper 4.2.1.188.

Render Link works on normal mode, but we look at same link in experience mode its hidden?

Razor Code:

```
<div class="c-home__cta">
    @RenderLink(x => x.CallToActionButton, new { @class = "c-btn c-btn--strong c-btn--large" }, isEditable: true)
</div>
```

Page source of experience editor mode:

```
<input id='fld_445CAE7C73764E3BBE7298BB2F1AC2F7_8381EE66B5A54D74B92C9171CD688959_en-GB_7_d1e84aa9693343f28b3b8ac3a0990b8d_35' class='scFieldValue' name='fld_445CAE7C73764E3BBE7298BB2F1AC2F7_8381EE66B5A54D74B92C9171CD688959_en-GB_7_d1e84aa9693343f28b3b8ac3a0990b8d_35' type='hidden' value="&lt;link linktype=&quot;internal&quot; text=&quot;Discover More&quot; querystring=&quot;&quot; target=&quot;&quot; id=&quot;{8CBC614A-F2B4-4842-81DA-BE4B57992547}&quot; /&gt;" /><span class="scChromeData">{"commands":[{"click":"chrome:field:editcontrol({command:\"webedit:editlink\"})","header":"Edit link","icon":"/temp/iconcache/networkv2/16x16/link_edit.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/link_edit_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edits the link destination and appearance","type":""},{"click":"chrome:field:editcontrol({command:\"webedit:clearlink\"})","header":"Clear Link","icon":"/temp/iconcache/networkv2/16x16/link_delete.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/link_delete_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Clears The Link","type":""},{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"Edit the related item","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/cubes.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/cubes_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the related item in the Content Editor.","type":"common"},{"click":"chrome:rendering:personalize({command:\"webedit:personalize\"})","header":"Personalize","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/users_family.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/users_family_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Create or edit personalization for this component.","type":"sticky"},{"click":"chrome:rendering:editvariations({command:\"webedit:editvariations\"})","header":"Edit variations","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/windows.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/windows_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the variations.","type":"sticky"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{445CAE7C-7376-4E3B-BE72-98BB2F1AC2F7}?lang=en-GB&ver=7","custom":{},"displayName":"Call to action button","expandedDisplayName":null}</span><span scFieldType="upm general link" scDefaultText="[No text in field]" contenteditable="true" class="scWebEditInput" id="fld_445CAE7C73764E3BBE7298BB2F1AC2F7_8381EE66B5A54D74B92C9171CD688959_en-GB_7_d1e84aa9693343f28b3b8ac3a0990b8d_35_edit"><link linktype="internal" text="Discover More" querystring="" target="" id="{8CBC614A-F2B4-4842-81DA-BE4B57992547}" /></span>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the text displayed to the user in the link is either the value from the Description field for external links or the name of the target Sitecore item, i think you have these values empty, you can override link text by contents parameter, so just add any text or blank space for contents if the page in edit mode :

```
@if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing)
{
 RenderLink(x => x.CallToActionButton, new { @class = "c-btn c-btn--strong c-btn--large" }, isEditable: true,contents: "some text")
}
else
{
RenderLink(x => x.CallToActionButton, new { @class = "c-btn c-btn--strong c-btn--large" })
}
```